# Isn't it obvious that I need assistance in editing my question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are often times when the question page is back-logged with questions on hold or closed. A percentage of the questions just need a simple edit, would be a great questions and still fit in the scope of the site. Because many of us are not theologians or even had the chance to farther their education there is no way they will be able to edit the question to fit the scope of this site. Is there a solution? Sometimes a simple solution is the best solution. How about an "Edit  Assistance?" option. Maybe a box the user could check? Maybe even a badge associated with it.That way the user or new user could anonymously ask for help without feeling embarrassed. The extra work that it would generate would be put towards the earning of a badge. What a wonderful "stepping stone" that could be for mentoring user's and new user's alike. Wow I just accidentally named the badge. The Communities thoughts on that?

Comment: Can you provide a few examples of questions you think could be salvaged by simple edits? I think this would help greatly in putting your question in context.

Comment: You might find the following question and answers helpful: [Why is putting a question “on hold” preferred over simply correcting the question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5822/21576)

Comment: If questions really do require some simple edits, we will make them rather than closing the questions. But if we can't tell what the asker is really trying to ask, we need to wait for them to explain, and to prevent confused answers from being posted, we close the question.

Comment: If you know your question is unclear before you ask it, you could talk to others in chat or here on Meta about how best to ask.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude Use Meta to ask about a question edit? What about an existing question. You have an example that I can follow?